# Change name of program associated with file "kind"

Tags: finder, macos

Is it possible in Sierra's Finder to change the name of a program associated with a file kind? For example, when in list view, a PDF lists the file kind as Adobe PDF Document, could this be changed to simply PDF?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This sort of looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is it that you're trying to accomplish by making changes such as this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the default application you are using to open PDF documents. To change it, right-click the file, click Get Info, click Expand on a section called "Open with", and there change the default app to Preview. After that, click the button "Change All...", and then click Continue. Keep in mind that this will change the default app used to open PDF documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually don't want to change the default app, but modify the descriptor text. I'm guessing I would mess with LaunchServices. So while I still want acrobat to open the file, I would love to find a way to change the text of the file type.

Answer (score 0):

PDF would be listed as "PDF Document" in the finder if the default app is Preview. In you case, It shows "Adobe PDF Document" because the default app is set to Adobe.

[image]